# What is the input format for word2vec features in SVM classification task?

Tags: python, classification, svm, word2vec

I am doing a binary classification task using linear SVM in scikit learn. I use nominal features and word vectors. I obtained the word vectors using the pretrained Google word2vec, however, I am not sure how SVM can handle word vectors as a feature.
It seems that I need to "split" each vector in 300 separate features (=300 vector dimensions), because I can't pass the vector as a whole to SVM. But that doesn't seem right, as the vector should be treated as one feature.
What would be the correct way to represent a vector in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vector of many features

From the perspective of an SVM, each dimension of a word vector would be a separate numeric feature - each dimension in that vector represents a numeric metric representing something different.

The same applies for non-SVM classifiers. For example, if you'd have a neural network, and your input features were that word vector of length 300 and (for the sake of a crude example) a bit stating whether that word was capitalized, then you'd concatenate those things and would have 301 numbers as your input; you'd treat that feature just as each of the 300 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response!

Comment: So you want to say we have to take the mean of word2vec features.

Comment: @BilalChandio no, I definitely did not want to say that; I intended to reassure OP that yes, "splitting" the vector to 300 independent features is the appropriate way to go. I can't see what in the answer suggests taking the mean of the features, if you can point out that interpretation, I'll change the answer to fix it.